# Objects are not valid as a React child when trying to pass a PDF document to backend using Express API in reactJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, pdf

I am trying to pass a rendered PDF document in my website to the backend in order for me to save it locally in a folder in my backend project directory.

but when I do so I get this error `Objects are not valid as a React child` in my backend server logs.

I am unsure how to achieve what I require. I need to save the generated PDF file in my website to my backend server in the project directory.

here is my code:

Frontend:

```
const downloadPDF = () => {
    Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/api/pdf", {
        PDF: <MyDocument/>
    }).then((res) => {
        alert(res)
        console.log(res);
    })
}



// Create Document Component

  const MyDocument = () => (
    <Document>
      <Page size="A4" orientation="landscape" style={styles.page}>
          <View style={styles.sectionHead}>
              <Image style={styles.image} src={logo}/>
              <Text style={styles.freightCode}>{freightType}</Text>
              <View style={styles.headDate}>
              </View>
          </View>

          {/*The body section of the pdf*/}
          <View style={styles.sectionInfo}>
              <View style={styles.sectionInfo1}>
              <Text style={styles.sectionInfoHeader}>COLLECTION:</Text>
              <Text style={styles.sectionInfoText}>{collname}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.sectionInfoText}>{collcompany}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.sectionInfoText}>{colladdress}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.sectionInfoText}>{collphone}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.sectionInfoText}>{collemail}</Text>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.sectionInfo2}>
              <Text style={styles.countryBlock}>{collcountry}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.locationBlock}>{collcity}</Text>
              </View>
          </View>
          {/*The body section of the pdf*/}
          <View style={styles.sectionCodeLocation}>
          <Text style={styles.collDelCode}>{collcountrycode} - {freightType} - {delcountrycode}</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.sectionInfo}>
              <View style={styles.sectionInfo1}>
              <Text>DELIVERY:</Text>
              <Text style={styles.sectionInfoText}>{delname}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.sectionInfoText}>{delcompany}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.sectionInfoText}>{deladdress}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.sectionInfoText}>{delphone}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.sectionInfoText}>{delemail}</Text>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.sectionInfo2}>
              <Text style={styles.countryBlock}>{delcountry}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.locationBlock}>{delcity}</Text>
              
              </View>
          </View>
          {/*The product section of the pdf*/}
          <View style={styles.sectionDetail}>
              <View style={styles.sectionInfo1}>
              <Text style={styles.weightCode}>Weight: {rangeval}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.weightCode}>Content: {shipContent}</Text>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.sectionInfo2}>
              <Text style={styles.weightCode}>Pieces: {pieces}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.weightCode}>Value: {shipValue} BHD</Text>
              </View>
          </View>
          {/*The product section of the pdf*/}
          
          <View style={styles.sectionAWB}>
              <Image style={styles.barcode} src={barcode}/>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.sectionFooter}> 
          <Text>*Frieght WAYBILL*</Text>
          <Text></Text>
          </View>
          {/*The product section of the pdf*
          <View style={styles.sectionDetail}>
          <Text>*Freight DOC*</Text>
          <Text>2021-08-15</Text>
          </View>*/}
      </Page>
    </Document>
  );



   <button className={'mt-2 btn-orange btn-orange-md getRateBtn rounded'} onClick={downloadPDF} name="pdf">Complete</button>
```

backend:

```
//Save PDF API
app.post("/api/pdf", (req, res) => {
    const pdf = req.body.PDF
    ReactPDF.render(pdf, `${__dirname}/example.pdf`);
});
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

One or more of the text tags contain objects as opposed to strings or floats which they should contain. So check all the ... in `<Text>{...}</Text>` to find the object which is not valid between html tags (react child).

Comment: How do i solve this issue? i need the document to be downloaded with these variables in the pdf

Comment: i deleted all the variables and still getting the same error. how come?

Comment: The error also says "If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead." i dont understand what that means